# Proof of the property of Limit Equivalence

Tags: calculus, limits

**Theorem:**

If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\lim_{x\to a}f_1(x)=\lim_{x\to a}g_1(x)=0$ and $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{f_1(x)}=1\quad\quad\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)}{g_1(x)}=1,$$

then prove that $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f_1(x)}{g_1(x)}$$

**Proof in the textbook:**

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g_1(x)}\frac{g_1(x)}{f_1(x)}\frac{f_1(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{f_1(x)}\frac{g_1(x)}{g(x)}\frac{f_1(x)}{g_1(x)}\stackrel{(1)}=$$

$$\stackrel{(1)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{f_1(x)}\lim_{x\to a}\frac{g_1(x)}{g(x)}\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f_1(x)}{g_1(x)}=1\cdot \frac{1}{1}\cdot \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f_1(x)}{g_1(x)}\implies$$

$$\implies \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f_1(x)}{g_1(x)}\ \ \ \square$$

---

But how to prove that (for $(1)$ to hold) $$\left(\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f_1(x)}{g_1(x)}\right)\in\mathbb R?$$

Because an important condition for $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ to hold is $\left(\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\right)\in\mathbb R$ and $\left(\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\right)\in\mathbb R$.

I've never been given another condition for which this could hold.

I'm only considering all of this in the real numbers.

Comment: You may want to break this up into two cases, case 1 where the limit does exist (and you're done), and case 2 where it doesn't, and try to show both sides diverge then

Comment: @Alan It is not clear to me what your idea is.

Comment: assume the thing you don't have, then you're done.   Then assume the opposite of the thing you have, and work from there to prove that the two limits don't exist

Comment: No need to answer this anymore: if $(\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x))\in\mathbb R$ and $(\lim_{x\to a}g(x))\in\mathbb R_{\neq 0}$, then clearly $(\lim_{x\to a}f(x))=\frac{\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)}{\lim_{x\to a}g(x)}\in\mathbb R$.